# Render an xml to a view

Tags: python, django, django-views

The scenario goes like this.

I get an atom file from a website (say A).  A third party will be request this atom file through my website (say B).

I am writing a Django app which will frequently poll website A and store it as a file.  Now, when a third party requests for the file through website B, I will have to display the file as xml in the browser.

My question is how do I render an entire xml file to a view in Django?

```
 render_to_response
```

expects a template.  I can't use a template as such.  I just need to display the file in the view.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to render a template, don't do so. `render` is just a shortcut to render a template. If you just want to display text, just pass it into the HttpResponse.

Since your data is in a file, this will work:

```
return HttpResponse(open('myxmlfile.xml').read())
```

although you should beware of concurrency issues, if more than one person is accessing your site at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So what is the best way to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Didnt work for me. Showed a `'module' object not callable` error.
silent1mezzo's answer seems to work fine.

Comment: How do you work around those concurrency issues?

Answer (score 21):

You just need to define the MIME type to `'text/xml'` using the `content_type` argument:

```
return HttpResponse(open('myxmlfile.xml').read(), content_type='text/xml')
```

Answer (score 19):

Do something like the below:

```
return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"}, content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

Comment: myapp/index.html is a template right? I don't have variable like foo->bar.  I just have an xml file.  I need to be using something like say return render(request,"myxmlfile.xml").  This xml file is not a template but a valid xml file.

Answer (score 4):

```
return render(request, 'products.xml', content_type='text/xml')
```

The `render` function can also work; you must add like jdelos' answer, simply adding the `content_type='text/xml'`.

Answer (score 2):

Just define the MIME type to 'text/xml' using the content_type argument.

`return render(request, 'xmltemplate.xml', {'foo':'bar'}, content_type='text/xml')`

In the xmltemplate.xml render the variables if you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <foo>{{ foo }}</foo>
</note>
```